How to change default behavior of VS Code to autostage?
I am using VS Code and its standard integration with git source control. Yesterday I encountered a bug where it doesn't Commit after typing in a Commit message and clicking Commit.  After some research I discovered it's not auto-staging so the Commit button will just work. How do I configure VS Code to go back to the previous behavior of auto-staging or auto-adding changes to a stage and make Commit work like before?

Enable this setting:
Git: Enable Smart Commit
Commit all changes When there are no staged changes
and see
Git: Smart Commit Changes
Control which changes are automatically staged by Smart Commit
// "all" or "tracked"
